# Regarding queues in QMGR

Tags: unix, mq

I installed IBM MQ in RHEL and now the queue manager is running good. But some particular queues are not responding while the payments.. I need the command to verify the status and to start the queue if its stopped. (commands to start and check status for a particular queue not a QMGR).

Comment: What made you think those queues are not responding - does your application get any error when putting or getting messages to/from those queues?

Answer (score 0):

If QMGR is running then your queue should be available, there is no particular command to start a queue.
To check all available queues in particular QMGR you can use below command:

runmqsc QMGR_NAME

DISPLAY QLOCAL(*)

and to check particular queue details you can use below command:

DISPLAY QLOCAL(queue_name)